# SwiftUI insertion transion is not working when view added

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying SwiftUI tutorial in apple developer page. now I'm following transition tutorial but my transition is not working when the view added.

here my code.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
    HStack() {
            
        // title
        Text(titleText)
            .font(.headline)
            .padding()
            
        Spacer()
            
        // button
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {    
                self.showDetail.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0))
                .padding()
        }
    }
        
    // detail
    if showDetail {        
        Text(contentText)
            .transition(.slide)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

I think the Text that has contentText, should appear with slide transition but when I press the Button, it just pop up. but when I press button again it disappear with transition. so removal transition is work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works as expected in Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Answer (score 4):

After some test I found some solution.

solution 1:
It is just bug of XCode canvas.
It works in the simulator or on a real machine.

solution 2. (if you really want to do in canvas)

```
Button (action : {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {    // add animation manually
        self.showDetail.toggle()
    }
}) {
    // label Image no change
}

if showDetail {
    Text(contentText)
        .transition(.slide)
        .animation(.easeInOut)    // match with withAnimation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done the tutorial you are talking about but I think it works pretty fine using the .move transition instead of the .slide transition.
Here's my code for the detail part (the rest is unchanged). I hope my answer can help you

```
if showDetail {
    Text(contentText)
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
        .padding()
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still not working...

when I touch the button Text just pop up and disappear with move transition.