# Transition is not working with ForEach nested in List with data from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, ios-animations

## Why this title?

Because `List`, `ForEach` and `CoreData` are the three major culprits in my opinion...well, if not simply `.transition()` itself.

## What I want

Basically I want, say, **a list of tasks** stored in the Core Data, and on tapping a task, it just disappears with `.transition(.scale)`. Several potential solutions that I have tried all failed both in the canvas and the simulators, two of which are on the stack overflow:

1. [SwiftUI insertion transion is not working when view added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800279/swiftui-insertion-transion-is-not-working-when-view-added)
2. [Transition animation not working in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730074/transition-animation-not-working-in-swiftui)

And the rest of attempts are just inserting the `.transition(.scale)` in all plausible places, and with/without `.animation(...)` attached.

---

## An overview of code

Here is the basic structure of my buggy view:

```swift
struct DeadlineListView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Deadline.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Deadline.dueTime, ascending: true)],
                  predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isCompleted == false"),
                  animation: Animation.linear(duration: 2)
    ) var deadlineList: FetchedResults<Deadline>
    
    // some other vars...
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            HStack {
                // some other views...
            }
            
            // --- Where things matter most ---
            List {
                ForEach(deadlineList, id: \.uid) { deadline in
                    Button(action: { isShowingDeadlineDetails = true }) {
                        DeadlineView(deadline: deadline)
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDeadlineDetails) {
                        DeadlineDetailView(deadline: deadline)
                    }
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                }
            }
            // --- Where things matter most ---
        }
    }
}
```

So technically I have a list of `Button`s, which look like `DeadlineView(...)`.

`DeadlineView(...)` has a button for the user to tap on to signal that a task is completed:

```swift
Button(action: {
    deadline.isCompleted = true
    deadline.objectWillChange.send()

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to save deadline isCompleted in DeadlineView!")
    }
}){
    // some View...
}
```

This button will make the `NSPredicate` ignore this task, and thus the task disappears from my list.

---

## What I actually get

Yes, it does do the animation. But the completed task is squeezed up by the task right below it without any visible(at least to me) `.transition(.scale)`.

---

## Where I have placed `.transition(.scale)`

Back to the first snippet:

```swift
            List {
                ForEach(deadlineList, id: \.uid) { deadline in
                    Button(action: { isShowingDeadlineDetails = true }) {
                        DeadlineView(deadline: deadline)
                        // .transition(.scale) 1. HERE!
                    }
                    // 2. HERE!
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDeadlineDetails) {
                        DeadlineDetailView(deadline: deadline)
                    }
                    // 3. HERE!
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    // 4. HERE!
                }
                // 5. HERE!
            }
            // 6. HERE!
```

**All with/without** `.animation(.linear(duration: 2))` **attached behind.**

---

#### Just another minor discovery

As you might have noticed, the `duration` for the animation(`2`) is pretty long so that it goes slowly enough for me to observe that it is not `transition`ing indeed.

But interestingly, it does not respond to that `duration`, be it `0.2` or `2`(Well, at least for me it does not seem to last for `2` seconds).

---

Any solutions or workarounds are welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893462/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi No, since the disappearance of my element attributes to the @FetchRequest, which I have declared with `animation:`, as suggested by that answer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've discovered that wrapping the ForEach in a VStack results in the correct item being animated, but results in unwanted layout changes.

Comment: No, I didn't. Helplessly I just left it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since transition affect many view here. You have to do the changes related to transition inside

```
withAnimation(Animation.easeIn) { //here you can change the animation you want
               //state changes should write here
            }
```

This link may helpfull
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3krC2c56ceQ

Comment: Thank you, but I did set the `animation:` for my `@FetchRequest`, which accounts for the changes of the view. CS193p does not help me to figure out where I have made mistakes either, sorry.